# SKLearn partial_fit() memory usage not constant

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, ram

I am using a `SGDClassifier` to classify text data. My preprocessing uses a BERT model, and this results in 768 features. Since I have 1.3 million examples in my training data, this requires me to use the `partial_fit()` method and process the data in batches.

However, when running `partial_fit()`, I noticed increasing memory used (about 0.2 GB on each call), which eventually crashes my Google Colab Notebook due to insufficient RAM. I also noticed that when calling my training procedure multiple times, this increase in RAM only occurs when I train on new examples (e.g. if I run from 0-2000, then RAM usage remains constant when training from 0-2000, but starts to increase beyond that). Why is this happening? Is `partial_fit()` storing values in memory?

Below is my code:

```
 from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
import gc


bert_classifier_model = SGDClassifier(loss='log')

#Training loop
gc.collect()
start = 0
for i in range(20000):
  print("initial")
  mem_report()
  X_train_slice = X_train[start:start + 64]
  y_train_slice = y_train[start:start + 64]

  X_train_processed = np.empty((64, 768))
  for j in range(len(X_train_slice)):
    with strategy.scope():
      temp_vals = preprocess([X_train_slice[j]])
      temp = bert(temp_vals)
    X_train_processed[j] = temp['pooled_output']

  bert_classifier_model.partial_fit(X_train_processed, np.ravel(y_train_slice), np.unique(y_train))
  start = start + 64
  print(start, " values processed")
  print("loop end")
  mem_report()
```

I am using a `MirroredStrategy` with a GPU. How can I limit the RAM usage to remain constant (or within Google Colab limits)?

Comment: maybe a memory leak